# Why does a POST response of 204 (no content) trigger the Angularjs error function?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angularjs application that uses `$http.post()` to make web service calls.  The method it calls has a `void` return type, and it generates a 204 (no content) response code.  This goes into the error function that is defined in the `.then()` callback, and prints "no element found" in the log.

If I return anything from the method, it returns the normal 200 response code.

**Why is a success code triggering the error function?**

Code as requested:

```
function myFn(inputData) {
    var d = { data: inputData };
    $http.post("../api/my/serverFn", d)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                $rootScope.AddMsg("Success");
            },
            function(response) {
                 // The 204 response goes here.
                 $rootScope.AddMsg("Error");
            });
}
```

The requested screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Posted code as requested.  I assume the server function is immaterial.

Comment: Did you inspect the error message angular is giving you? ...

Comment: That's odd, from [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), *A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called.*

Comment: I don't see any error message, just the "no element found" in the console.  Am I missing an Angularjs specific error log somewhere?

Comment: Now post a screenshot of the browser dev tools proving that you indeed receive a 204 from that request You could also log the response status, differently, from each callback. If that is true, then you must have an http interceptor rejecting the promise in case of 204.

Comment: You called it.  I have a HTTP interceptor that was changing it into an error.  Could you please post your comment about the HTTP interceptor so I can give you credit for the answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9532

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't natively consider a 204 response as an error. The investigation revealed that there was in fact an http interceptor in the stack that rejected the promise if the response received had a 204 status, turning the successful response into an error.

Comment: Thanks again for the help